# Create new dataframe from existing dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to create a new dataframe containing specific columns from an existing df. My code runs correctly but I get the SettingWithCopyWarning. I have researched this warning and I understand why it exists (ie: chained assignments). I also know you can simply turn the warning off.

However my question is, what is the correct way to create a new dataframe using specific columns from an existing dataframe in order to not get this warning. I don't want to simply turn the warning off,...because I presume there is a better (more pythonic) way to do this than how im currently doing it. In other words, I want a completely new dataframe to work with, and I don't want to just copy all the columns.

The below code passes the existing dataframe to a function (removeBrokenRule). The new dataframe is created which contains only 4 columns from the existing df. I then perform certain operations on the new df and return it.

```
newdf = removeBrokenRule('Forgot rules', df)

def removeBrokenRule(rule, df):
    newdf = df[['Actual ticks', 'Broken Rules', 'Perfect ticks', 'Cumulative Actual']]
    newdf['Actual ticks'][newdf['Broken Rules'] == rule] = newdf['Perfect ticks']
    newdf['New Curve'] = newdf['Actual ticks'].cumsum()
    return newdf
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: By default and this has nothing to do with pandas, this is python, variables will be passed by reference, so if you want to take a deep copy of the passed df, then you should do `newdf = df[['Actual ticks', 'Broken Rules', 'Perfect ticks', 'Cumulative Actual']].copy()` also you second line should be this: `newdf.loc[newdf['Broken Rules'] == rule,'Actual ticks'] = newdf['Perfect ticks']` to avoid chained assignment

Comment: Excellent, thanks @EdChum that sorted it out. The pandas site doesn't seem to have any documentation on loc. Busy trying to research more about it.

Comment: See this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy this explains why you should  not use chained indexing, do you want me to post an answer detailing my comment above?

Comment: Thanks again @EdChum .I was aware of loc but couldn't find any documentation on it to actually learn exactly what it does. Busy going through your link now.